# Moving a file to another directory in Batch using %USERPROFILE%?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, user-profile, file-move

So, I have a folder with two files in it, *Test.cmd*, and *Test.txt*.
I'm trying to move *Test.txt* to another directory using the *Test.cmd* file with **%USERPROFILE%**.
Here's my code so far:

```
move "%d%Test.txt" "%USERPROFILE%AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

The output read: **The system cannot find the file specified.**

I tried adding ' \ ' after the %d% and %USERPROFILE% but that was no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should write something like that :

```
Move "%~dp0Test.txt" "%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

Comment: Hmm... Still can't find the file. I know it isn't a problem with the placements of the files because I added `start %d%Test.txt` and it opened successfully.

Comment: @Datonebassdude What represente `%d%` for you ?

Comment: '%d%' is just the directory. in my case, '%d%' outputs as: 'C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Documents\Code'

Comment: And what happens if you try like that ?  `Move "C:\Users\josh\OneDrive\Documents\Code\Test.txt" "%Appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" `

Comment: Ohhh... I see, I accidentally marked 'Test.txt' as a hidden file and that prevented it from being found by the script. Your answer worked. Thanks and apologies! Not sure why you can start hidden files but not move them though...